# Embedded JavaScript - render HTML to page

Tags: javascript, html, seo, ejs

I'm currently rewamping a site that uses Embedded JavaScript(http://embeddedjs.com/), it works fine however there is a problem with SEO - due to the fact that the HTML is hidden.

You can't see the markup when viewing source - do any of you know of a way to render the HTML to the page, so Google's spiders can access the content?

This is the website: http://shop.cbb.dk/Catalog.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website is pretty much incompatible with search engines as they do not run JavaScript.

If you want them to index your site, you'll have to create a version which contains the content that should be crawlable.